# How to update values in JDBC using Resultset

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, resultset

I want to chang all thd "id"'s values to int k, using ResultsSet.

I am having errors-null exception.

I get the error at the updateInt("ID",k);

Error:
"Cannot suppress a null exception. Self-suppression not permitted"

```
int k=1;
try {
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    String  urlCn="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDb";
    Connection   cn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlCn, "omer", "1234");
    Statement stmt = cn.createStatement();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rs.next()) {
        if(rs.getInt("ID")!=k)
            rs.updateInt("ID", k);
        k++;
    }
    rs.close();
    cn.close();
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(addQuestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}           
catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(addQuestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you null...

Comment: i get the error at the updateInt("ID",k);

Comment: Check the data type of your table. It could be ID is an autonumber not allowed to be edited. See if it is a primary key also which prevents duplicate ids. K could retain a value that in later rows will be updated!

Comment: @Parfait id is a regular type, integer

Comment: Autonumbers are integer types with a special designation of database. Can you confirm it is not auto incremented? Also, is it a primary key?

Comment: @Parfait not a primary key, not a auto incremented key.. its a regular key that i called id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution using another way,ITS WORK, without the Resultset.

```
        int k=1;
        int oldId=1;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            String  urlCn="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDb";
            Connection   cn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlCn, "omer", "1234");
            Statement stmt = cn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            PreparedStatement st;
            while (rs.next()) {
                st = cn.prepareStatement("update QUESTIONS set id = ? where id = ?");
                oldId=rs.getInt("id");
                if(oldId!=k){
                    st.setInt(1,k);
                    st.setInt(2,oldId);
                    st.executeUpdate(); 
                }
                k++;
            }
            rs.close();
            cn.close();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(addQuestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }           
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(addQuestion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  `updateRow()` to your code like this:

```
   rs.beforeFirst();
   while (rs.next()) {
     if(rs.getInt("ID")!=k){
      rs.updateInt("ID", k);
      rs.updateRow();
       k++;
       }
     }
```

And try to replace  `rs.first();`  with `rs.beforeFirst();`
Try to take alook at [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/updating-result-sets.htm)